# actionscript 3 and using fonts

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, fonts

How can I make my strings and text attributes bold in my actionscript code?

I'm working with the code behind pattern so i have an mxml component with a text attribute. I then have my actionscript component where I concatenate three text attribute and set them as the text property on the mxml text component.

I want to be able be flexible with the styles of each text field I concatenate. I want the first text bold and the last bold however. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use different font weights for a text, you have no other choice than creating 2 text components (Label, Text, ...).

If you use external fonts, be sure to embed both normal and bold fonts :

```
@font-face
{
    src:                    url("calibri.ttf");
    fontFamily:             calibri;
    advanceAntiAliasing:                    true;
    fontWeight:             normal;
}

@font-face
{
    src:            url("calibrib.ttf");
    fontFamily:     calibri;
    fontWeight:     bold;
}
```

and set some styles in your css like :

```
.calibri16
{
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:calibri;
    color: #666666;
}

.calibri16b
{
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:calibri;
    color: #666666;
}
```

You can then set the styleName property of your text components :

```
<HBox>
<Label id="myLabel" styleName="calibri16b" text="This is bold" />
<Label id="myLabel2" styleName="calibri16" text="and regular" />
</HBox>
```

In Action Script :

```
myLabel.styleName = "calibri16b";
myLabel2.styleName = "calibri16";
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample application. I assume you have the assets directory with century.ttf file in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:WindowedApplication xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Style>
        @font-face {
            src: url("assets/century.ttf");
            fontFamily: Century;
            fontStyle: normal;
            fontWeight: normal;
        }
        .myClass {
            fontFamily: Century;
        }
    </mx:Style>
    <mx:Label text="Different font" styleName="myClass"  />
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Not all fonts expose all variants. Some fonts will give you normal only, some give you all: normal, bold, italic.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In *ActionScript* if you don't want a TextFormat, that is:

```
myTextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.bold = true;
myTextField.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
```

...you can also use htmlText:

```
myTextField.htmlText='<b>Bold</b> not bold <b>Bold again!</b>';
```